# Singleton in java not create instance

Tags: java, singleton

I am trying to create a singleton instance in my java servlet. But I have some kind of problem I can't find.

I execute this in one method:

```
 RegisterHandler reg = RegisterHandler.getInstance();
```

And in registerHandler I have the getInstance method:

```
private static RegisterHandler instancia ;  

public static RegisterHandler getInstance() {  
    if(instancia==null){ //SI ES NULL
       instancia = new RegisterHandler(); //LO INSTANCIAMOS
    }
    return instancia;  
}
```

I think it should return a new instance if it doesn't exist or the existing one but the first time I try to execute it, it enters in instancia==null and crash. No error given.

Any idea?

I add my constructor:

```
private RegisterHandler() { 
    try {
        this.publisher = new AMQEventPublisher("failover:tcp://127.0.0.1:9009");
    } catch (NormalException e) {
        log.error("Error",e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `RegisterHandler` constructor do?

Comment: What's in the constructor of `RegisterHandler`?  Is it swallowing exceptions?

Comment: There is no code you have show which would cause the program to crash.  If it is throwing an exception, it is in code you haven't shown.  Can you give us the exception, the stack trace and which line the exception was thrown?

Comment: It doesn't give exceptions. That is the problem I cannot know why it is failing. but the line new Regist... is not executing and the program doesn't continue from that point

Answer (score 0):

Declare `instancia` volatile.
Also to avoid possible duplications of RegisterHandler use double locking:

```
private static volatile RegisterHandler instancia;
private static final Object instanciaLockObject = new Object();

public static RegisterHandler getInstance() {  
    if(instancia==null){ //SI ES NULL
       synchronized(instanciaLockObject) {
            if(instancia==null){
               instancia = new RegisterHandler(); //LO INSTANCIAMOS
            }
       }
    }
    return instancia;  
}
```

The pattern is known as double-checked locking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: Perhaps you could add when you would use this instead of an enum with one instance.

Comment: Also create a private constructor just to avoid external programs creating an instance of RegisterHandler

Comment: double locking also has vulnerabilities, use SingletonHolder or enum pattern

Comment: I know no vulnerabilities in double-checked locking in Java (5+). If you declare instance volatile, it works ok since Java 5 (in Java 4 there were issues, but c'mon, it's Java 8 soon).

As for Enum with single instance - that won't be lazy-initialised anymore.

Comment: I suppose you have null-pointer exception somewhere inside RegisterHandler constructor. Not in the code you've posted.

Answer (score -2):

I would also, just to be sure, set instancia to null to start with.  Could be me being paranoid, but I believe in the "better safe than sorry" rule with code.

Comment: But the first time I enter, instancia is null. I go inside that if condition.

Comment: `instancia` will be null by default by definition.

Comment: I just set to null as a matter of style, as I come from a C background, but it doesn't hurt, in terms of readability :).